# Is there any alternative to repetitive if statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Here's my code, it seems kind of repetitive, but I couldn't figure out a way to make it differently. (It works okay btw, but it seems to me it's a bit "unclean")

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Type in the first parameter: "))
        num2 = int(input("Type in the second parameter: "))
        num3 = int(input("Type in the third parameter: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You have to type in a number. ")

while True:
    if num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:
        c = num1
        if c * c == num2 * num2 + num3 * num3:
            print("Your triangle is a pythagorean triangle")
        else: 
            print("Your triangle isn't a pythagorean triangle")

    elif num2 > num1 and num2 > num3:                             # c - hypotenuse 
        c = num2 
        if c * c == num1 * num1 + num3 * num3:
            print("Your triangle is a pythagorean triangle")
        else: 
            print("Your triangle isn't a pythagorean triangle")

    elif num3 > num1 and num3 > num2:        
        c = num3 
        if c * c == num2 * num2 + num1 * num1:
            print("Your triangle is a pythagorean triangle")
        else: 
            print("Your triangle isn't a  pythagorean triangle")

    elif num1 == num2 and num2 == num3 and num1 == num3:
        print("There's no such thing as a pythagorean triangle with all sides the same, try again")

        again = str(input("Do you want to continue? [Y/n]\n"))
        if again == "Y" or again == "y":
            pass
        else: 
            break
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort the numbers?

Comment: Since your code works, you may have better luck here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As I understood, you shouldn't 2 loops. Place the code block of 2nd while loop inside the try block of first while loop (after the existing code block), finally use **continue** statement in place of **pass**. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the max function and a bit of math to reduce the need for if cases.
Example below without the loops for repetition

```
num1 = int(input("Type in the first parameter: "))
num2 = int(input("Type in the second parameter: "))
num3 = int(input("Type in the third parameter: "))

if num1 == num2 == num3:
    print("There are no pythagorean triangle with all sides equal")
    exit(1)

c= max(num1,num2,num3)

if c * c == num1 * num1 + num2 * num2 + num3 * num3 - c * c:
    print("Your triangle is a pythagorean triangle")
else: 
    print("Your triangle isn't a pythagorean triangle")
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `num1 > num2 and num1 > num3` you may easily do `num2 < num1 > num3` and it will work just the same.

On the other hand I'd sort the numbers and don't worry about different combinations:

```
num1, num2, num3 = sorted( [num1, num2, num3] )

# here the num1 < num2 < num3 so you may use a single check
if num1 * num1 + num2 * num2 == num 3 * num3 : # etc...
```